# how to read a csv file and split a line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .csv file  and when i open the file it looks something like this

```html
r1   r2   r3  
0,3  0,3  02 
43   5    3  
3    3,2  01
```

Every row is separated by a coma.

¿How can i split every line on the file, so i can put it in a list and will end up like this.

```html
list = [['0,3','0,3','02'],['43','5','3'],['3','3,2','01']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `csv.reader`:

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', 'r', newline=' ') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    next(reader)
    lst = list(reader)
```

`lst` becomes:

```
[['0,3', '0,3', '02'], ['43', '5', '3'], ['3', '3,2', '01']]
```